# JPA using Mysql/Oracle - No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm a bit newbie and I've been trying to link my Hibernate code to database for some days, without success. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TestMySqlHibernate
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at testDummyEntrance.DummyInterface.main(DummyInterface.java:17)
```

The persistence.xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="TestMySqlHibernate">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testalan" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="alan" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="password" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The dummy function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestMySqlHibernate");
    EntityManager em=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I've also checked that the persistence.xml file is correctly located under src/main/resources/META-INF, and is included in build path.

I'm probably doing something terribly stupid, but I can't figure out what this could be. I've checked out about 10 possibilities and still the same. If it helps, I can connect with Data Source Explorer, and tried both Oracle and MySql.

Using last version of MySql, and driver 8.0.11, all in local, in same machine.

I can post POM.xml or any other data if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.javavids.hibernate.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>testHibernateMaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>
                jboss-javaee-6.0-with-transactions
            </artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>20040616</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>20030211.134440</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jboss-modules</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Beta3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: yes please post the POM I assume that you don't have the hibernate entity manager dependency declared

Comment: Hi, @SimonMartinelli, thanks for the reply.
I think i have all I need (and much more), but no idea if there is still something missing...

Comment: Try : <persistence-unit name="TestMySqlHibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> in persistence.xml

Comment: Remove  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> in persistence.xml this should be found automatically

Comment: That's it guys!
Seems that removing provider tag is the key. I also added the RESOURCE_LOCAL that Nicholas suggested, but the key seems to be not having the provider tag. With your permission, I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @SimonMartinelli, I found it. Also, @K.Nicholas suggestion is correct, the resource type is not JTA and has to be clarified. Kudos to them.

The resulting persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestMySqlHibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testalan?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="alan" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="password" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Please note their changes (remove provider tag and add transaction-type property) and the UTC addition that I had to do using MySQL.

Not sure if has something to do with the driver version or what, but the provider tag is a runtime-breaker with driver 8.0.11.

Thanks both for the solution guys, you solved my headache!

EDIT: As newbie... how can I vote your answers as positive?